# Export form filter data with condition statements

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am only a student and new to VBA I am trying to export a user form that will have some filtered data by the user so I could code the output to get all filtered data on a form like this

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryResults", acFormatXLS
However, how can I call this to add on my condition statements after the export so I have to create my own export so I can call excel VBA and then go into the book I am creating and add in condition statements. So I tried my best and failed the following code does work but it should and I cannot figure out why I can not export my filtered data from a form with the condition statements in the form? Access will add on the condition statements in a pdf form! why can I not get it in excel with the simple "Print" function

```
    Public Sub cmdExport_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Dim x As Excel.Application
Dim r As Recordset
Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
Dim l As Long
Dim c As New Collection

Set r = Me.Recordset
Set x = New Excel.Application
x.Visible = 1

If x.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then x.Workbooks.Add

Set w = x.Worksheets(1)

For l = 0 To r.Fields.Count - 1
    If Me.Controls(r.Fields(l).Name).ColumnHidden Then
        c.Add l + 1
    End If
    w.Range("a1").Offset(0, l).Value = r.Fields(l).Name
Next l

w.Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset r

For Each i In c
    w.Columns(i).Hidden = True
Next i

For l = r.Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
    If w.Columns(l).Hidden = True Then
        w.Columns(l).Delete
    End If
Next l
Call worksheetformat

On Error GoTo 0




''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Condition Statment

'Call worksheetformat




End Sub

Public Sub worksheetformat(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim MyRange As Range
Call SelectAllCellsInSheet(ActiveSheet.Name)
For Each Cell In MyRange
    If Cell.Value Like "COMPLETE" Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 48
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "GO TO SOURCE INFO" Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "CANCELLED" Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38

    Else
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
    Next





End Sub
Sub SelectAllCellsInSheet(SheetName As String)
    lastCol = Sheets(SheetName).Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Lastrow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets(SheetName).Range("A2", Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your *condition statements*? All I see is you hiding columns.

Comment: Proofread your narrative and edit question - `following code does work but it should` is missing `not`. Do you have error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Have you set breakpoint and step debugged? Is all this code in Access VBA?